# Prevent a class from access to one of its own field

Tags: c#, field

In C#, is there a way to prevent a class from accessing one of its own fields?

For example:

```
class MyClass()
{
    private object field;
    public object Property
    {
        get { return field; }
        set { field = value; }
    }

    public void myMethod()
    {
        field = null; // forbidden
        Property = null; // allowed
    }
}
```

The reason is to always use the setter so some functions are called.

Comment: How else do you expect to set the property value? If you only want to set it in the constructor, you can make it `readonly`? Though to be honest, I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I will explain more

Comment: You don't trust the code in your own class?

Comment: I don't trust me ^^. I can forget to call property instead of field and there will be no error

Comment: If you prefix your private variables with underscore, it's quite clear they are private.

Comment: It's a good idea ! I will do that, thank you

Comment: You need to be really careful with this kind of code, and this is why you are seeing the need to "not trust yourself" here. Instead, you should consider rewriting the class as having side effects when setting properties is often very confusing, especially to people who aren't aware of what might happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way to prevent a class accessing its own field if you want to Set its value at some point in an accessor.

Comment: Technically this is wrong, there is the `readonly` keyword that prevents certain access.

Comment: @DavidG but this would prevent the OP from setting the value in the accessor. I modified my reply to make this clear - thanks for the critique.

Comment: What about using inheritance to hide the private field then? My point is that this is just not correct.

Comment: Thank you i will use the solution given by  L-Four, using underscore. Inheritance will make my code disturbing I think

Comment: @DavidG - I'm intrigued - can you give a quick snippet of how a class (on its own, without another class) can prevent itself accessing its own private variables ? If you can show how this can be done I'll happily withdraw my answer.

Comment: There's an example in the linked duplicate. Note, I'm not saying it *should* be done, just that it *can* be done.

Comment: @DavidG - yes; but it uses another class (inheritance) and the member being blocked isn't really "one of its own fields" - the member is its parent classes field, so I maintan my answer to be correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

This way you don't need a backing field. 
But I don't think you are looking for such.

```
Class MyClass()
{
    public object Property { get; set; }

    public void myMethod()
    {
        Property = null; // allowed
    }
}
```

Comment: With `Property { get; set; }` I can add methods/tests in `set` (see my edit).